# Finding intersection and projection points for a set of labelled coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project where I need to find the minimum x and minimum y coordinates for a set of labelled points. Additionally, I need to determine the intersection point of the two lines passing through the minimum x and minimum y coordinates.

I have a list of points, where each point is represented as a list in the following format:

```
[[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], [x4, y4]], [x_center, y_center], label]
```

Here, `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], [x4, y4]]` represents the four corners of a rectangle enclosing the labelled point. `[x_center, y_center]` represents the coordinates of the centre of the rectangle, and the `label` is a numerical value associated with the point.

I need to find the minimum x and minimum y coordinates of the labelled points, and then determine the intersection point of the lines passing through the minimum x and minimum y coordinates. Additionally, I want the projection points to have the same format as the zero points, including the label coordinates.

I have tried implementing a function `find_actual_points(points, pixel_tolerance=1)` to achieve this, but I am having trouble getting the correct results. Here is my current implementation:

```
def find_actual_points(points, pixel_tolerance=1):
    sorted_points_by_x = sorted(points, key=lambda point: point[1][0])  # Sort points by X center coordinate
    x_zero_point = sorted_points_by_x[0]  # Point with the minimum X center coordinate

    sorted_points_by_y = sorted(points, key=lambda point: point[1][1])  # Sort points by Y center coordinate
    y_zero_point = sorted_points_by_y[-1]  # Point with the minimum Y center coordinate

    x1, y1 = x_zero_point[1]
    x2, y2 = y_zero_point[1]

    if abs(y1 - y2) <= pixel_tolerance:
        raise Exception("Lines are parallel")

    intersection_x = x1 - ((x1 - x2) * y1) / (y1 - y2)
    intersection_y = y1 - ((y1 - y2) * x1) / (x1 - x2)

    # Calculate label ratios for the axes
    x_label_ratio = (y1 - intersection_x) / (y1 - x1)
    y_label_ratio = (y1 - intersection_y) / (y1 - x1)

    # Add the intersection point of the minimum x and minimum y lines
    actual_points = []
    actual_points.append([[intersection_x, intersection_y], [x_zero_point[2], y_zero_point[2]]])

    # Calculate projection points for the other labeled coordinates
    for point in points:
        coords = point[1]
        label = point[2]

        # Calculate the x-axis projection of the minimum x and minimum y lines intersection
        x_projection = intersection_x + (coords[0] - intersection_x) * x_label_ratio

        # Calculate the y-axis projection of the minimum x and minimum y lines intersection
        y_projection = intersection_y + (coords[1] - intersection_y) * y_label_ratio

        actual_points.append([[x_projection, y_projection], label])

    return actual_points
```

When I run this code with the provided example points:

```
[[[[4.071428571428571, 217.07142857142858], [19.92857142857143, 217.07142857142858], [19.92857142857143, 230.92857142857142], [4.071428571428571, 230.92857142857142]], [12, 224], 1.0],
 [[[4.071428571428571, 301.07142857142856], [19.92857142857143, 301.07142857142856], [19.92857142857143, 314.92857142857144], [4.071428571428571, 314.92857142857144]], [12, 308], 0.0],
 [[[8.0, 50.0], [17.0, 50.0], [17.0, 63.0], [8.0, 63.0]], [12, 56], 3.0],
 [[[9.0, 130.0], [18.0, 130.0], [18.0, 142.0], [9.0, 142.0]], [13, 136], 2.0],
 [[[18.0, 305.0], [28.0, 305.0], [28.0, 316.0], [18.0, 316.0]], [23, 310], 0.0],
 [[[132.0, 303.0], [153.0, 303.0], [153.0, 319.0], [132.0, 319.0]], [142, 311], 20.0],
 [[[251.0, 303.0], [273.0, 303.0], [273.0, 319.0], [251.0, 319.0]], [262, 311], 40.0],
 [[[370.0, 303.0], [391.0, 303.0], [391.0, 319.0], [370.0, 319.0]], [380, 311], 60.0],
 [[[489.0, 305.0], [508.0, 305.0], [508.0, 318.0], [489.0, 318.0]], [498, 311], 80.0]]
```

I do not get the expected results.

Also, this is the visualisation of the points, which might be helpful.

[image: Also, this is the visualisation of the points, which might be helpful.]

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to fix the code and obtain the desired results. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I need something like that.

[image: EDIT: I need something like that.]

EDIT: For the example list I have provided, the following points are on the same line.

For the line parallel to the Y-axis:

```
[[4.071428571428571, 217.07142857142858], [19.92857142857143, 217.07142857142858], [19.92857142857143, 230.92857142857142], [4.071428571428571, 230.92857142857142]], [12, 224], 1.0],
 [[[4.071428571428571, 301.07142857142856], [19.92857142857143, 301.07142857142856], [19.92857142857143, 314.92857142857144], [4.071428571428571, 314.92857142857144]], [12, 308], 0.0],
 [[[8.0, 50.0], [17.0, 50.0], [17.0, 63.0], [8.0, 63.0]], [12, 56], 3.0],
 [[[9.0, 130.0], [18.0, 130.0], [18.0, 142.0], [9.0, 142.0]], [13, 136], 2.0]
```

For the line parallel to the X-axis,

```
 [[[18.0, 305.0], [28.0, 305.0], [28.0, 316.0], [18.0, 316.0]], [23, 310], 0.0],
 [[[132.0, 303.0], [153.0, 303.0], [153.0, 319.0], [132.0, 319.0]], [142, 311], 20.0],
 [[[251.0, 303.0], [273.0, 303.0], [273.0, 319.0], [251.0, 319.0]], [262, 311], 40.0],
 [[[370.0, 303.0], [391.0, 303.0], [391.0, 319.0], [370.0, 319.0]], [380, 311], 60.0],
 [[[489.0, 305.0], [508.0, 305.0], [508.0, 318.0], [489.0, 318.0]], [498, 311], 80.0]
```

And I need to achieve the minimum labelled X point and minimum labelled Y point, which are

```
[[[18.0, 305.0], [28.0, 305.0], [28.0, 316.0], [18.0, 316.0]], [23, 310], 0.0]


[[[4.071428571428571, 301.07142857142856], [19.92857142857143, 301.07142857142856], [19.92857142857143, 314.92857142857144], [4.071428571428571, 314.92857142857144]], [12, 308], 0.0]
```

respectively.

And I think their orthogonal intersection of the centre points between the two lines will be `[12, 310]`.

And the projections of the points on the line parallel to the X-axis will be like [X point, 310], the projections of the points on the line parallel to the Y-axis will be like [12, Y point].

I am having trouble to find the minimum point on the line parallel to the X-axis and the minimum point on the line parallel to the Y-axis. Please note that one of the labels might be greater than other. I need a general solution. I think I can do the rest.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't seem to correlate with your sample data in that you discuss a situation where yo have a list containing four lists of corner coordinates, followed by a list of center coordinates, and a label. You state you want to determine the minimum coordinate and draw a line through the center point.  Yet, your sample data shows a list of lists, please clarify how this is interpreted.  Also, please clarify what you mean by "I want the projection points to have the same format as the zero points, including the label coordinates.", since the label doesn't have coordinates..

Comment: @itprorh66 The example list comes from a scientific plot. The corners initially come from PaddleOCR and we do not need those. We only need the centre coordinates. I have to get the minimum X label and minimum Y label first and then find the intersection of their centres, which is between the lines represented by the existing points (see figure). (continued)

Comment: @itprorh66 This intersection is our (minimum x, minimum y) point, let's call it the actual minimum point. And then, existing points are on X and Y axis, as you see in the figure. I need to move the existing points on the X-axis to the actual minimum point's coordinate by lowering its y coordinate and the same for the Y-axis.

The actual minimum point is represented as [[intersection_x, intersection_y], [x_zero_point[2], y_zero_point[2]]]. (continued)

Comment: @itprorh66 Here, [intersection_x, intersection_y] are actual centre coordinates and [x_zero_point[2], y_zero_point[2]] are labels representing the point on the scientific figure. I also need the         actual_points.append([[x_projection, y_projection], label]) line as the same format, e.g.         actual_points.append([[x_projection, y_projection], [label_x, label_y]]) 

Corners are in pixels, centres are in pixels and labels are in the units of any scientific figure.

Comment: @itprorh66 I have added another figure to the question to explain what I need.

Comment: I am still confused for example you show the points which you claim are on the same line parallel to the Y-axis, yet to be parallel to an axis they must all have the same Y value.  In your data this is not the case since the Y values include 217.07142857142858, 301.07142857142856,  314.92857142857144, and  others.  Why are these point, in your opinion, parallel to the Y axis?

Comment: @itprorh66 No, they should have the same point on the X axis. They have 12 and 13. I have 1 px tolerance here for this example.

Comment: yes you are correct, the fact being that the x coordinates are not the same either

Comment: @itprorh66 This is the tolerance. The pixel difference can be 1 px.

Comment: What pixel?  Also, I doubt the difference between 4.071428571428571 and 19.92857142857143 could possibly be 1 px

Comment: @itprorh66 The numbers you talk about are for the corners of the rectangle. I mean, the points can be shift one pixel. For example, the centre points of the line parallel to the Y-axis has 12 and 13 for the X coordinate. Here, we have one pixel shift and it is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by separating the points. I have did it by my phone, so the coding might be better.

```
def find_actual_points(points, pixel_tolerance=1):
    x_parallel_line, y_parallel_line = separate_lines(points, pixel_tolerance)
    lines_x = sorted(x_parallel_line, key=lambda point: point[2])
    lines_y = sorted(y_parallel_line, key=lambda point: point[2])
    x_zero_point = lines_x[0]  # The smallest labeled point on the X axis
    y_zero_point = lines_y[0]  # The smallest labeled point on the Y axis

    x1, y1 = x_zero_point[0][0]
    x2, y2 = y_zero_point[0][0]

    if abs(y1 - y2) <= pixel_tolerance:
        raise Exception("Lines are parallel")

    # Find intersection points of x and y axes using the equations of the lines
    intersection_x = y_zero_point[1][0]
    intersection_y = x_zero_point[0][1][1]

    # Add the central intersections of x_zero_point and y_zero_point
    actual_points_x = []
    actual_points_y = []
    actual_points_x.append([[intersection_x, intersection_y], [x_zero_point[2], y_zero_point[2]]])
    actual_points_y.append([[intersection_x, intersection_y], [x_zero_point[2], y_zero_point[2]]])

    # Calculate other points
    for point in lines_x[1:]:
        coords = point[1]
        label = [point[2], y_zero_point[2]]

        # Finding the projection on the x-axis of (0, 0)
        x_projection = coords[0]

        # Finding the projection on the y-axis of (0, 0)
        y_projection = intersection_y

        actual_points_x.append([[x_projection, y_projection], label])
    for point in lines_y[1:]:
        coords = point[1]
        label = [x_zero_point[2], point[2]]

        # Finding the projection on the x-axis of (0, 0)
        x_projection = intersection_x

        # Finding the projection on the y-axis of (0, 0)
        y_projection = coords[1]

        actual_points_y.append([[x_projection, y_projection], label])

    return actual_points_x, actual_points_y


def separate_lines(points, pixel_tolerance=1):
    x_parallel_line = []
    y_parallel_line = []

    for i in range(len(points) - 1):
        if abs(int(points[i][1][1]) - int(points[i + 1][1][1])) <= pixel_tolerance:
            if points[i] not in x_parallel_line:
                x_parallel_line.append(points[i])
            if points[i+1] not in x_parallel_line:
                x_parallel_line.append(points[i+1])
        elif abs(int(points[i][1][0]) - int(points[i + 1][1][0])) <= pixel_tolerance:
            if points[i] not in y_parallel_line:
                y_parallel_line.append(points[i])
            if points[i+1] not in y_parallel_line:
                y_parallel_line.append(points[i+1])
    return x_parallel_line, y_parallel_line


points = [[[[4.071428571428571, 217.07142857142858], [19.92857142857143, 217.07142857142858], [19.92857142857143, 230.92857142857142], [4.071428571428571, 230.92857142857142]], [12, 224], 1.0],
          [[[4.071428571428571, 301.07142857142856], [19.92857142857143, 301.07142857142856], [19.92857142857143, 314.92857142857144], [4.071428571428571, 314.92857142857144]], [12, 308], 0.0],
          [[[8.0, 50.0], [17.0, 50.0], [17.0, 63.0], [8.0, 63.0]], [12, 56], 3.0],
          [[[9.0, 130.0], [18.0, 130.0], [18.0, 142.0], [9.0, 142.0]], [13, 136], 2.0],
          [[[18.0, 305.0], [28.0, 305.0], [28.0, 316.0], [18.0, 316.0]], [23, 310], 0.0],
          [[[132.0, 303.0], [153.0, 303.0], [153.0, 319.0], [132.0, 319.0]], [142, 311], 20.0],
          [[[251.0, 303.0], [273.0, 303.0], [273.0, 319.0], [251.0, 319.0]], [262, 311], 40.0],
          [[[370.0, 303.0], [391.0, 303.0], [391.0, 319.0], [370.0, 319.0]], [380, 311], 60.0],
          [[[489.0, 305.0], [508.0, 305.0], [508.0, 318.0], [489.0, 318.0]], [498, 311], 80.0]]

print(find_actual_points(points))
```

This code takes a list of points as input and returns the actual points of the intersections of the X and Y axes along with their labels. The `separate_lines` function is used to separate the points into two lists, `x_parallel_line` and `y_parallel_line`, based on their alignment with the X and Y axes. The find_actual_points function then calculates the intersection points and the projections of (minimum labelled x, minimum labelled y) on the axes. Finally, it returns the desired output in the form of two lists, `actual_points_x` and `actual_points_y`.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not absolutely certain what you are looking for in the end, given a list of lists where each internal list contains two points you should be able to find the coordinates with minimum x and minimum y coordinates using the builtin function sort as illustrated below:

```
pts = [[6.2, 1.6], [5.8, 4.2], [1.6, 2.4], [1.6, 5.8]]
low_point = sorted(pts)[0]
```

This yields:
[1.6, 2.4]  which is the point in the lower left position

Knowing this point you can easily define the line between this point and the center

if you have a list of lists of the form:

```
list_of_points = [[[[8.0, 50.0], [17.0, 50.0], [17.0, 63.0], [8.0, 63.0]], [12, 56], 3.0],
 [[[9.0, 130.0], [18.0, 130.0], [18.0, 142.0], [9.0, 142.0]], [13, 136], 2.0],
 [[[18.0, 305.0], [28.0, 305.0], [28.0, 316.0], [18.0, 316.0]], [23, 310], 0.0]]
```

You can do:

```
for pt_defn in list_of_points:
    low_point = sorted(pt_defn[0])[0]
    print('Min Pt = C{low_point}, Center Pt = {pt_defn[1]}, Label = {pt_defn[2]}')
```

Which Produces:

```
Min Pt = C{low_point}, Center Pt = {pt_defn[1]}, Label = {pt_defn[2]}
Min Pt = C{low_point}, Center Pt = {pt_defn[1]}, Label = {pt_defn[2]}
Min Pt = C{low_point}, Center Pt = {pt_defn[1]}, Label = {pt_defn[2]}
```

Comment: This is not working in my case since I have list of lists. I have tried many sorting approaches. I also need a general solution, I mean not only for the example list I have provided.

Comment: I also used lambda.

Comment: I edited my answer to address the list of lists, not sure what else you need.

Comment: Thank you for the edit but I have two axis in one list and how can I find the minimum label for the both axis?

Comment: low_point is the coordinate with the lowest x and lowest y values, thus it defines the lower left corner of a box assuming the coordinate system grows in the Y direction vertically and grows in the x direction horizontally

Comment: I mean, if you look at the figure the points are ordered on the lines, which are parallel to the X and Y axis, respectively. I need to find the lowest points by the label on both lines respectively. I need a general solution, not only for the example list I have provided.

Comment: For the example list, I want to achieve following: `[[[4.071428571428571, 301.07142857142856], [19.92857142857143, 301.07142857142856], [19.92857142857143, 314.92857142857144], [4.071428571428571, 314.92857142857144]], [12, 308], 0.0]` for the line parallel to the Y axis and `[[[18.0, 305.0], [28.0, 305.0], [28.0, 316.0], [18.0, 316.0]], [23, 310], 0.0]` for the line parallel to the X axis. The labels are same in this example but it might be different.

Comment: I clearly don't understand what you are looking for.  Please edit your question to show the logic behind how given your sample input you arrive at your expected output, with this as a guide maybe we can help